# How to track bookmarklet usage using Image in Matomo?

Tags: javascript, analytics, matomo

I want to count users that use my bookmark in my Piwik/Matomo instance.

This is my code:

```
x = new Image();
x.src = 'https://piwik.jcubic.pl/matomo.php?idsite=7&rec=1&action_name=bookmark&urlref=' + location.href;
```

The problem is that when I open the statistic for today I don't see website with bookmark or reference on which the script was executed. I did this in incognito mode, so there was not cookie that disabled tracking for my browser.

The bookmark is REPL for Scheme language, so it's more likely be website that have Scheme learning resource or YouTube with video about Scheme. I think it's not the problem that I will track the url when bookmark was executed, there will be no information about the actual user so I think this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to encode your href

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams({idsite: 7, rec: 1, action_name: 'bookmark', urlref: location.href});
const url = new URL('https://piwik.jcubic.pl/matomo.php')
url.search = searchParams.toString()

x.src = url.href;
```

Then you will have a URL like this with encoded special chars:

```
"https://piwik.jcubic.pl/matomo.php?urlref=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63977752%2Fhow-to-track-bookmarklet-usage-using-image-in-matomo"
```

Comment: It also don't work. I'm not sure. Maybe I need to wait one day, before they will appear. Will check tomorrow.

Comment: Did you checked it on the network tab in the browser dev tools, it can be blocked by Adblock. There are instructions about debugging https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_58/ and https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#debugging-the-tracker

Comment: I've got request in dev tools, it returns 200 response code. in incognito mode I don't have any browser extensions enabled.

Comment: I've also tried guest account in Chrome (I think this is blank account I've created, don't remember) because in FAQ there is info that Matomo handle do not track tag.

Comment: if needed you can also debug the matomo.php requests, by enabling debug in tracker, see: https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#debugging-the-tracker

Comment: After enabled debugging I've found that I had limit on URL it was excluding urls outside the list. The solution would be to enable debugging.